# How can I force chrome to only download one file at a time?

Tags: google-chrome, download, download-manager

Right now, files simultaneously download which drastically lowers the download speed

Comment: it's not a limit set by the browser, it's set at system-level. If you need instructions to reduce the concurrency limit for the entire machine, see http://www.ehow.com/how_12169537_change-number-simultaneous-downloads-chrome.html

Answer (score 2):

try the *Chrono* extension for chrome. In *Options* there is a field which lets you change the simultaneous number of downloads. https://goo.gl/FF69cP